# Jquery datatable pace

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, datatables

i want to pace the datatables with up,down,left,right button the tab button is working but the way button is not working. How can create this function ?
I use it

> https://datatables.net/

EDİTED ;

```
<div class="table-responsive " style="height: 400px; overflow-y: auto;">
 <table id="TBL" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="tdbicim">ONE</th>
      <th id="tdbicim">TWO</th>
      <th id="tdbicim">Three</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="Tbody">
    <tr>
      <td id="tdbicim"><input width="100%"/></td>
      <td id="tdbicim"><input width="100%"/></td>
      <td id="tdbicim"><input width="100%"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="tdbicim"><input width="100%"/></td>
      <td id="tdbicim"><input width="100%"/></td>
      <td id="tdbicim"><input width="100%"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="tdbicim"><input width="100%"/></td>
      <td id="tdbicim"><input width="100%"/></td>
      <td id="tdbicim"><input width="100%"/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is source code i want to use ways button too .

Comment: The question is incomplete, you should explain better. A code snippet helps.

Comment: Look deeper into the documentation. There is an extension for exactly that.

Comment: I editted code now @AndrésMorales

Comment: Nice @ZibianDomichi, but you are provided only the HTML part of your source. The scripts required (jQuery, DataTables) are loaded correctly? Where do you call `$('#TBL').DataTable();`?

Comment: Another 2 questions @ZibianDomichi: Why nine input boxes, and... why DataTable? Do you want the user can switch into input boxes using the direction arrows?

Comment: @AndrésMorales yes sir i want to user can switch into input boxes..